# Why are the gradients not equivalent when using loss.backward() v.s torch.auto.grad?

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient-descent, autograd, stochastic-gradient

I ran into this weird behavior when trying to "manually" optimize a network's parameters via SGD. When attempting to update the model's parameters using the following way, it works just fine:

```
for _ in trange(epochs):
    for x, y in train_loader:
        x, y = x.to(device, non_blocking=True), y.to(device, non_blocking=True)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(m(x), y)
        grad = torch.autograd.grad(loss, m.parameters())
        with torch.no_grad():
            for p, g in zip(m.parameters(), grad):
                p -= 0.1 * g
```

However, doing the following throws off the model completely:

```
for _ in trange(epochs):
    for x, y in train_loader:
        x, y = x.to(device, non_blocking=True), y.to(device, non_blocking=True)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(m(x), y)
        loss.backward()
        with torch.no_grad():
            for p in m.parameters():
                p -= 0.1 * p.grad
```

But to me, both methods should be equivalent. And upon further inspection, when comparing the values of `g` from `grad` with the values of `p.grad` from `m.paramters()`, it turned out that the gradient values are **not** the same! I also tried removing `with torch.no_grad():` and doing the following, but it didn't work either:

```
        for p in m.parameters():
            p.data -= 0.1 * p.grad
```

Can somebody please explain why is this happening? Shouldn't the gradients in both methods have the same values (keeping in mind that both models `m` are identical)?

**REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE:**

Ensure reproducibility:

```
device = torch.device('cuda')
torch.manual_seed(0)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(0)
np.random.seed(0)
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

Load the data:

```
T = transforms.ToTensor()
train_data = datasets.MNIST(root='data', transform=T, download=True)
test_data = datasets.MNIST(root='data', transform=T, train=False, download=True)

BS = 300
epochs = 5
LR = 0.1

train_loader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=BS, pin_memory=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=1000, pin_memory=True)
```

Define the model to be optimized:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, out_dims):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, out_dims, 3, stride=3, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(out_dims, out_dims * 2, 3), nn.BatchNorm2d(out_dims * 2), nn.ReLU())
        self.conv3 = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(out_dims * 2, out_dims * 4, 4, stride=2, padding=1), nn.BatchNorm2d(out_dims * 4), nn.ReLU(), nn.Flatten())
        self.fc = nn.Linear(out_dims * 4 * 16, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        return nn.Sequential(*tuple(self.children()))(x)


m1 = Model(5).to(device)
m2 = deepcopy(m1)  # "m2.load_state_dict(m1.state_dict())" doesn't work either
```

Training and evaluation:

```
# M1's training:
for _ in trange(epochs):
    for x, y in train_loader:
        x, y = x.to(device, non_blocking=True), y.to(device, non_blocking=True)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(m1(x), y)
        grad = torch.autograd.grad(loss, m1.parameters())
        with torch.no_grad():
            for p, g in zip(m1.parameters(), grad):
                p -= LR * g
                
# M1's evaluation:
m1.eval()
acc1 = []
with torch.no_grad():
    for x, y in test_loader:
        x, y = x.to(device, non_blocking=True), y.to(device, non_blocking=True)
        _, pred = m1(x).max(1)
        acc1.append(metric(pred, y).item())

print(f'Accuracy: {np.mean(acc1) * 100:.4}%')


# M2's training:
for _ in trange(epochs):
    for x, y in train_loader:
        x, y = x.to(device, non_blocking=True), y.to(device, non_blocking=True)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(m2(x), y)
        loss.backward()
        with torch.no_grad():
            for p in m2.parameters():
                p -= LR * p.grad

# M2's evaluation:
m2.eval()
acc2 = []
with torch.no_grad():
    for x, y in test_loader:
        x, y = x.to(device, non_blocking=True), y.to(device, non_blocking=True)
        _, pred = m2(x).max(1)
        acc2.append(metric(pred, y).item())

print(f'Accuracy: {np.mean(acc2) * 100:.4}%')
```

Comment: I cannot replicate this. Can you post a minimal working reproducible example?

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos hey thanks a lot for your interest. I included a simple reproducible example, hope this helps.

Comment: I think I got it: try `m2.zero_grad()` before every `loss=...` in the second loop. I'll explain in an answer if that fixes things

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos yes that does fix it! Thanks a lot, please put it as an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: ha! glad it worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while to figure out, but the problem was in `loss.backward()`. Unlike `autograd.grad()` which computes and returns the gradients, the inplace `backward()` computes and **accumulates** the gradients of participating nodes in the computation graph. In other words, the two will have the same effect when used to back-prop once, but every repetition of `backward()` will add the currently computed gradients to all previous ones (hence the divergence). Resetting the gradients using `model.zero_grad()` fixes stuff.